# How to enable hotspot service on jailbroken ios device

Tags: ios, root, jailbreak, tether

I am trying to turn Personal Hotspot service on/off programmatically.

I have jailbroken iPhone 5S with iOS 8.3

I have tried using some of the private frameworks (Sharing, ManagedConfiguration) and changing the values of the DynamicStores MISManager settings.

I've tested those solutions in an application with root privileges.

Anyone out there with some better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get hotspot service working on jaibroken iOS device from code but not using private frameworks.

I've used hopper app to disassemble some of the system services to find what is triggering the hotspot service.

Once I got the info I used cycript to hack into those services and launch the hotspot.

This solution is based on having cycript on your device and running your app with root privileges.